# System Out of Memory

Tags: c#, azure, memory, out-of-memory

I am trying to sync some data from an azure db to a local db. I generally have it working for one particular data set but when I move to a larger more robust data set I'm getting an Internal Server Error, which I have discorvered is a system out of memory.

System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
↵   at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
↵

[image]
Detailed Error code from server -
Detailed Error Information:

Module
   ManagedPipelineHandler

Notification
   ExecuteRequestHandler

Handler
   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler

Error Code
   0x00000000

Here is my code.  It is failing in the the success status code block which is then giving me the internal error.  I've been looking at this a few days and can not see anything out of the ordinary as why one group would work and the other wouldnt.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thank  you

```
            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler, false))
            {

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(syncServerURL);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
                client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);

                int syncGroups = 0;
                int index = 1;
                foreach (var gt in SyncGroup.GroupTypes)
                {
                    syncGroups = SyncGroup.GroupTypes.Count;
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation($"{System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString()} {index} of {syncGroups} starting to process ");
                    try
                    {
                        var syncGroup = SyncGroup.CreateSyncGroup(gt, syncStore.Id, db);
                        var syncGroupWrapper = SyncGroupWrapper.GetSyncGroupWrapper(syncGroup);

                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation($"{System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString()} - Sending {gt} data to azure.");

                        var sgw = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(syncGroupWrapper, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
                        var content = new StringContent(sgw.ToString(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                        var response = await client.PostAsync($"api/sync/ss", content); 

                        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError($"{response.StatusCode} {response.ReasonPhrase}");
                            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError($"{response.StatusCode} {response.RequestMessage}");
                            return InternalServerError(new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase));
                        }

                        var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation($"{System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString()} - Received {gt} data back from azure.");
                        syncGroupWrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }) as SyncGroupWrapper;
                        if (syncGroupWrapper == null) return InternalServerError();

                        await syncGroupWrapper.Group.SaveGroup(db);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        while (ex.InnerException != null)
                        {
                            ex = ex.InnerException;
                        }

                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);
                    }
                    index++;
                }

                return Ok();
            }
```

Comment: What is the size of the content you post? And how long does it take to be processed server side?

Comment: The one I have working is about 129744 the one that isnt working is 3144.  I was looking at content-length originally thinking that would be my issue.  Alot of articles said that really didnt matter

Comment: Have you tried to remote debugging on Azure Web Site to get the detailed error? You could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio).

Comment: This ultimately lead me to the answer if you want to post as answer